# Scale of Curve to effect Location of "Set of objects"

Tags: rigging, parent

I'm trying to create a rig in Blender and i'm fairly new to the program, I am wanting to scale a Bezeir circle that will in turn shrink the distance of a set of objects in a circular motion.

I really can't wrap my head around it, any help would be greatly appreciated[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Circular Path

If the shape of the curve is a circle, this can be achieved even without a curve.  You just need a few empties placed in correct positions (around the circle) and parented to some object whose `Scale` will be adjusted to *move* the visible objects (`Cube` in my example)

[image: 3D view]

[image: Outliner]

When the circle is scaled, each empty moves as if they are parented to a certain location on the (circular) curve.  But in fact this is just simple parent transformation.

[image: Copy location constraint]

Instead of parenting the cube to an empty, we can just copy its location using `Copy Location` constraint.

## Non-Circular Path

[image: Follow path constraint]

A more generalized solution is to use a `Follow Path` constrains on the visible objects and constrain them to the curve directly.

Important thing here is to give each visible object a difference offset (on the curve). If we have 6 objects, for example, each one should have an offset `100 / 6 * i` (where `i` is the index of the object, `0, 1, 2, ...`).

[image: Egg]

This method should work on any kind of curve, open or closed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your in depth response this was really helpful and has solved my problem!

Comment: You are welcome.